# PlusAndroidSample

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Has anyone used the PlusAndroidSample ? I am getting the dreaded "R cannot be resolved into a variable" error in the com.example.adnroid.auth and i've tried everything from the variuos "R cannot be resolved"-threads in here. I imported the project and followed the instructions but no.
Anyone?

Comment: there ar e2 packets in the src but only one in the gen. and the one in  the gen has the same name as the "working" one.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your imports. Is there any import android.R ? if yes delete that. If there is not, remove your R.java from the generated java files and let to regenerate it. Hope it works!

Comment: did you check the xml layout files ? Maybe there is some error in one of the files and the app cannot build. Check each layout for errors

Comment: the thing is that this is an imported project sample from google. it "SHOULD" work right?